# How can iOS 11’s screen recording not record the control center screen?

Tags: ios, screen-recording

We can start the screen recorder in the control center but this part also goes into the recording. How can we skip this part?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** As of the GM release, a 3 second timer has been implemented allowing time to dismiss Control Center.   The end of the clip may still require editing, however.

**Disclaimer: As of this posting, iOS 11 is in Public Beta and may change before final release.**

As of writing, it does not appear that a 'timer' can be set to indicate when to start the recording.

The recording does indeed start when the button on the control center is tapped.  This can be edited out of the final recording by trimming the video.

- Go to the video in the **Photos** app.
- Use the yellow handles (indicated by the `<>` symbols) to trim the beginning and end of the video as desired.

[image: Trim Video]

Comment: so I suppose as of right now, there is no way to configure it to start recording after 3 seconds or something...

Comment: Not yet, but is it still in beta so we'll wait and see.  I'm hoping a timer can be implemented, but at least for now the recording can be edited.  Cheers!

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Great news! This was fixed in a later beta.